# Problems with Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to transcribe a German podcast which I have both on my pc and my Google Storage bucket. I'm using [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-google-speech-to-text-api-to-transcribe-long-audio-files-1c886f4eb3e9) as a reference.

Here's my code:

```
frame_rate, channels = frame_rate_channel('pod.wav')
gcs_uri = 'gs://callsaudiofiles21/pod.wav'

client = speech.SpeechClient()
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
sample_rate_hertz=frame_rate,
language_code='de-DE')

transcript = ''

operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
response = operation.result(timeout=10000)

for result in response.results:
    transcript += result.alternatives[0].transcript
```

But it stops at the `operation` line, outputting `TypeError: long_running_recognize() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. The tutorial is from a year ago, so something must have changed in the API since. I'm not sure what to modify though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're using an old library version.

From [Google async recognizion example](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech_transcribe_async_gcs-python), this two options seems to be equivalent:

```
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(
        request={"config": config, "audio": audio}
    )
```

or

```
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
```

BTW - Take a look also at the official [Google Codelab for Speech to text](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-speech-text-python3/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) - they always have up-to-date examples.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
operation = client.long_running_recognize(
        request={"config": config, "audio": audio}
    )
```